# JavaScript Arrow Function Syntax

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I am studying JavaScript and have been learning how to use arrow function syntax and have come across this problem that I don't understand thoroughly and I feel this would be the best place to ask my question since I haven't found the exact answer I'm looking for on this issue, yet. So, here is the code.

`let bigNumbers = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];`

`let smallNumbers = bigNumbers.map(num => num / 100);`

Now my question is, where does num come from? Is this a bucket to store the new values being mapped when running the code? I understand that we create a new variable that will return a new array since elements from the array have been modified? I'm not quite sure, which is why I need clarification. Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

`num` is simply an argument of your arrow function:

```
bigNumbers.map(num => num / 100)
```

...is shorthand for, and functionally equivalent to:

```
bigNumbers.map((num) => {
    return num / 100;
});
```

In your example, using the `Array` `map()` method, the `num` argument is the item in the array being iterated over in that instance.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

`num` is a function argument (or a *Method* property in your case; `.map()` being a Method of `Array.prototype`).

`num`... **You can name it whatever you want.**

What's basic here is ***what it represents***.  If you take a look at some documentation like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

> ```
> var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
>     // Return element for new_array
> }[, thisArg])
> ```

you can see that the **first argument** represents the **currentValue**, in other words the current iterating value.

```
let smallNumbers = bigNumbers.map(num => num / 100);
```

which translates to

```
let smallNumbers = bigNumbers.map((num) => {
    return num / 100;
});
```

which further *translates* to

```
var smallNumbers = bigNumbers.map(function(currentValue) {
    return currentValue / 100; // currentValue is the currently iterating value
});
```